# JavaFX Designer

Tags: graphics, designer, javafx

At the moment I'm using JavaFX only for fun and learning it.

What I find annoying is designing the graphics by coding them and watching the result in a preview window - you know what I mean?

Is there something for JavaFX like what Expression Blend is for Silverlight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is support for exporting from Adobe tools. It is called [JavaFX Production Suite](http://javafx.com/docs/gettingstarted/production_suite/).

Answer (score 8):

You might take a look at the JavaFX SceneBuilder. http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/scenebuilder/1/user_guide/jsbpub-user_guide.htm

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Tor Norbye talk about JavaFX designer at JavaOne 2009 conference and he published screenshot on his blog.

http://blogs.oracle.com/tor/entry/finally_over

Comment: I use NetBeans, but where's the designer? I can drag&drop components in the source, so the source is "automagically" created and I can use the preview, but I don't find a way to "draw" like i.e. I can do for SVG in Inkscape.